# Google maps to Open Street map

Tags: google-maps, maps

I have a directory test site in which I've added Google maps and I have some poi into map....But the problem is that my api key as free shows the map without restrictions just one time. After that google map shows a message that is only for development use...Is there any way without pay to have Google map free use for many page visitors? Or the only solution is to use alternative maps like open Street and so on? What alternative is easier in coding to change Google maps? If you have an descriptive example, will help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own mapserver and do updates and everything around it by your own. Please provide some more informations.

Please be aware that the Open Streetmap Database is free, the Open Street map API Server is not. There are some limitation for using that Service in your application.

Also there are several other Providers on the Market that might be interresting for you.
https://www.mapbox.com/

Comment: Mapbox is a good alternative, as I saw on their website. I've created my account on it and I have followed some useful instructions in order to add the map and poi on it... A question about this. I read pricing policy and is free for the first 50000 views per month...do you know, these views are in regard that users have different IP?

Comment: They count views. That means open a map on longitude an Latitude by zoom Level 7 counts as one View. Zooming in to zoom Level 8 counts as another View. IP Adresse are Not important by that method of counting.